# Permutation of numbers that there are all modulo M .

Tags: permutations, arithmetic, integers

Let's say I have $M-1$ integers, all of them different from each other, and all of them smaller than integer M: $$1,2,3...M-1$$
I multiply each of them by another integer S, and write the result modulo M .
So, I get another group of numbers :$$r_1,r_2...$$
I would like to prove that the new group that I found is permutation of the ordinary group:$$1,2,3...M-1$$

Could someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: This is false if $(M,S) \neq 1$.

Comment: $\gcd (M,S)\neq 1$, i.e. there is an integer $k >1$ so that $k\mid M$ and $k\mid S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(M,S)\neq 1$ then this result is false. (Take any two not coprime numbers and you'll see).

Assuming $(M,S)=1$ then consider the set $\mathcal{S}=\{S\cdot k\mod M\mid k=0,\ldots,M-1\}$.

Proving that $\mathcal{S}$ is the original set (disregarding order) is equivalent to proving that if $Sa\equiv Sb\pmod{M}$ with $a,b$ from the original set, then $a\equiv b\pmod{M}$.

If $Sa \equiv Sb$ then $Sa-Sb\equiv 0\Rightarrow S(a-b)\equiv 0 \Rightarrow M\mid S(a-b)$. Since $(M,S) = 1$ then $M\mid (a-b) \Rightarrow a\equiv b\pmod {M}$.